# Как должен выглядеть код, чтоб счетчик работал правильно?

Tags: java

Программа должна вести учёт арендованных и возвращённых самокатов.  Но при нажатии в выборе пункта 2, программа прибавляет самокат один раз. Последующий выбор пункта 2 не добавляет еще один самокат. Что надо исправить в коде, чтоб счетчик работал правильно?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Сколько самокатов доступно для аренды?");
        int availableScooters = scanner.nextInt(); // Считайте количество доступных самокатов с клавиатуры

        System.out.println("Сколько самокатов арендовано?");
        int scootersInUse = scanner.nextInt(); // Считайте число арендованных самокатов с клавиатуры

        Scooter scooter = new Scooter(availableScooters, scootersInUse); // Создайте новый объект класса Scooter

        System.out.println("Что вы хотите сделать?");
        System.out.println("1 -- Узнать текущую стоимость проката");
        System.out.println("2 -- Выдать самокат");
        System.out.println("3 -- Принять самокат");
        System.out.println("4 -- Завершить работу");

        while (true) { // реализуйте непрерывный ввод команд
            System.out.println("Введите команду:");
            int command = scanner.nextInt(); // Считайте команду с клавиатуры

            if (command == 1) {
                scooter.getPrice(scootersInUse, availableScooters); // Вызовите нужный метод класса Scooter
            } else if (command == 2) {
                scooter.rentScooter(scootersInUse, availableScooters); // Вызовите нужный метод класса Scooter
            } else if (command == 3) {
                scooter.returnScooter(scootersInUse, availableScooters); // Вызовите нужный метод класса Scooter
            } else if (command == 4) {
                System.out.println("Сеанс работы завершён!");
                break; // Завершите ввод команд и работу программы
            } else {
                System.out.println("Введён неверный код команды.");
            }
        }
    }
}

class Scooter {
    static int availableScooters;
    static int scootersInUse;
    int defaultPrice = 8; // Цена аренды по умолчанию
    int additionalPrice = 5; // Добавочная стоимость при повышенном спросе

    public Scooter(int inputAvailableScooters, int inputScootersInUse) {
        availableScooters = inputAvailableScooters;
        scootersInUse = inputScootersInUse;
    }

    public void getPrice(int scootersInUse, int availableScooters) {
        if (availableScooters == 0) { // Проверьте, есть ли доступные самокаты
            System.out.println("Нет доступных самокатов.");
        } else {
            int currentPrice = defaultPrice + additionalPrice * ((scootersInUse + 1) / availableScooters); // Посчитайте текущую стоимость проката
            System.out.println("Текущая стоимость проката: " + currentPrice + " руб/мин");
        }
    }

    public void rentScooter(int scootersInUse, int availableScooters) {
        if (availableScooters == 0) { // Проверьте, есть ли доступные самокаты
            System.out.println("Доступных самокатов не осталось.");
        } else {
            int currentPrice = defaultPrice + additionalPrice * ((++scootersInUse) / availableScooters--); /* Посчитайте текущую стоимость проката,
            увеличьте число арендованных самокатов и уменьшите число доступных */
            System.out.println("Выдайте самокат по цене " + currentPrice + " руб/мин");
            System.out.println("Самокатов в аренде: " + scootersInUse);
            System.out.println("Самокатов доступно: " + availableScooters);
        }
    }

    public void returnScooter(int scootersInUse, int availableScooters) {
        if (scootersInUse == 0){ // Проверьте, есть ли самокаты в аренде
            System.out.println("Все самокаты уже возвращены.");
        } else {
            // Уменьшите число арендованных самокатов и увеличьте число доступных
            System.out.println("Самокат принят.");
            System.out.println("Самокатов в аренде: " + scootersInUse);
            System.out.println("Самокатов доступно: " + availableScooters);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе `Scooter` вы пытаетесь уменьшить и увеличить у переменных параметров самого метода а не класса `Scooter`. Нужно дописать `this."название переменной"`

**UPD**

На примере метода  `rentScooter`

```
public void rentScooter(int scootersInUse, int availableScooters) {
        if (availableScooters == 0) { // Проверьте, есть ли доступные самокаты
            System.out.println("Доступных самокатов не осталось.");
        } else {
            int currentPrice = defaultPrice + additionalPrice * ((++scootersInUse) / availableScooters--); /* Посчитайте текущую стоимость проката,
            увеличьте число арендованных самокатов и уменьшите число доступных */
            System.out.println("Выдайте самокат по цене " + currentPrice + " руб/мин");
            System.out.println("Самокатов в аренде: " + scootersInUse);
            System.out.println("Самокатов доступно: " + availableScooters);
        }
    }
```

У вас есть в классе `Scooter` два `static variable`

```
static int availableScooters;
static int scootersInUse;
```

Инициализируете вы их в конструкторе класса.

Но когда дело доходит до методов класса `Scooter`, то вы с ними не работаете а работаете с параметрами метода, то есть в строке

```
int currentPrice = defaultPrice + additionalPrice * ((++scootersInUse) / availableScooters--); /* Посчитайте текущую стоимость проката,
            увеличьте число арендованных самокатов и уменьшите число доступных */
```

вы увеличиваете не перменную класса, а переменную из параметров метода, если исправить строку на

```
int currentPrice = defaultPrice + additionalPrice * ((++this.scootersInUse) / this.availableScooters--); /* Посчитайте текущую стоимость проката,
            увеличьте число арендованных самокатов и уменьшите число доступных */
```

то вы будете работать уже с переменными самого класса.

**UPD 2.0**
Исходный код

```
while (true) { // реализуйте непрерывный ввод команд

    System.out.println("Введите команду:");
    int command = scanner.nextInt(); // Считайте команду с клавиатуры

    if (command == 1) {
        scooter.getPrice(scootersInUse, availableScooters); // Вызовите нужный метод класса Scooter
    } else if (command == 2) {
        scooter.rentScooter(scootersInUse, availableScooters); // Вызовите нужный метод класса Scooter
    } else if (command == 3) {
        scooter.returnScooter(scootersInUse, availableScooters); // Вызовите нужный метод класса Scooter
    } else if (command == 4) {
        System.out.println("Сеанс работы завершён!");
        break; // Завершите ввод команд и работу программы
    } else {
        System.out.println("Введён неверный код команды.");
    }
}
```

В местах где передается `scootersInUse`  и `availableScooters` вам нужно передовать переменные класса `Scooter`, а вы передаете переменные которые были созданы в методе `main` выше

Должно быть типа такого

```
scooter.getPrice(scooter.scootersInUse, scooter.availableScooters); // Вызовите нужный метод класса Scooter
```

Comment: Спасибо всем за советы. Они конечно помогут более опытному разработчику. Но я ученик самого начального уровня и ваши советы мне пока не помогают.

Comment: @Владимир обновил ответ, надеюсь объяснил лучше)

Comment: Очень хорошее объяснение. Жаль, не сработало))

Comment: @Владимир обновил свой ответ, нашел ошибку

Answer (score 1):

> Что надо исправить в коде, чтоб счетчик работал правильно?

Убрать параметры у методов класса Scooter

Comment: + в методе `returnScooter` нет изменения статичных полей класса